# sqlite shift rowid in multiple records

Tags: sqlite, shift, rowid

Hello i have an sqlite db with many records like 10540 record they are ordered by creation time , i want to shift like a record in the middle and like to do it automatically

for example :

```
select * from table1 where id >= 8521; 
UPDATE Table1 SET id = id +1 ;
```

does not work i get Error: Result: UNIQUE constraint failed: 
so i want to shift up all records from 8521 to the last record and get place in the 8520 place for example so i can insert my record in that place of table .
even the

```
id = select max(id)+1
```

does not work how can i increment the id from last record to the needed record so i can put a place in the records db

Comment: Is the column `id` autoincrement?

Comment: This is a curious thing to want to do. If you can tell us why you want to do that we may be able to suggest a better solution.

Comment: yes the id is autoincrement , let's say the user bob wrote something at id = 1 then user john wrote another thing at id = 2 etc etc ... user x wrote at id = 5411 ,
i want to edit the id = 5410 and put john before x without taking any record place. for example if john wrote at id = 5410 and forgot to save or something and he tells the db admin so i can edit for him the db and put him at that place

Comment: i know i can do it manually by setting records id from 8521 to the last record to NULL and then use the reindex statement and insert a line with id of 8520 to the table but it's not handy

Comment: If you want to order rows by creation time, put the creation timestamp in a column and use that with ORDER BY. Don't try to make the rowid do something it isn't meant for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple update statement would fail, as it would try to create duplicate values in the primary key. 
What you can do is this:
First update the column to the negatives of the values they should have:

```
update table1
set id = -(id + 1)
where id > 8520;
```

Now there are no duplicates and you just need to update again to the positive values:

```
update table1
set id = -id
where id < 0;
```

This will do the trick, but any kind of updating the primary key is **not** a recommended practice

Comment: thanks for your answer it worked . i do not do this all the time i only edit when asked to do so and help people thanks for help